# plotly 3d surface - change cube to rectangular space

Tags: r, 3d, aspect-ratio, plotly

I would like to have a 3d plot that is not in a cube, since my z data is 10 times smaller than the scale of x and y axis. How do you set it up so that the 3d plot is not in a cube, but in a rectangular shape instead? (I would like x, y, z axis to be on the same scale as well. That is, x and y are from 0 to 100, while z is from 0 to 10 in this example:)

```
zz = matrix(c(1:10), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)

plot_ly(z=zz, x = c(1:100), y = c(1:100), type = 'surface') %>% 
  layout(autorange = F, aspectmode = 'manual', 
         scene = list(xaxis = list(range = c(0,100)),
                      yaxis = list(range = c(0,100)),
                      zaxis = list(range = c(0,20))
         ))
```

If I set the range of zaxis to (1:20), then the scale is messed up and the surface is still in a cubic space, which I don't want to have.

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the [aspectratio option](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-aspectratio).

```
plot_ly(z=zz, x = c(1:100), y = c(1:100), type = 'surface') %>% 
  layout(
    autorange = F, 
    aspectmode = 'manual', 
    scene = list(
      zaxis = list(range = c(0,20)),
      aspectratio = list(x = 1, y = 1, z = 0.2)
    )
  )
```